# Loading and displaying on VGA monitor a Background image in DE2-115's SDRAM

Tags: memory, fpga, intel-fpga

I would like to load a background image which I currently have saved as a .bmp into the DE2-115's SDRAM. I would then like to display this background image on a VGA-monitor (640x480). I will then be drawing additional images overlaid to this background image.

I am using NIOS II by the way.

I have implemented games using a VGA controller such as brick breaker but they simply had solid colors which I would draw in .sv code quite easily.

If I want to draw this .bmp to the monitor what steps should I take? Should I draw it from software in C or from hardware using a vga controller and reading from memory? Lastly how should I upload the .bmp to the SDRAM?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to store two frames, a background, and a foreground. The foreground image should have an alpha channel to support transparency. Then, before writing the image to the VGA, layer (or blend) the foreground on top of the background to create one image. Any foreground pixels not used would be transparent, allowing the background to show through.

If you're using Nios II, the [Altera University Program](https://www.altera.com/support/training/university/materials-ip-cores.html) has some good example programs and IP cores to do basic video processing.

Your image should be converted to whatever raw format you're storing it in. Examples could include RGB, YCbCr, Greyscale, etc. in various bit-widths (16-bit, 24-bit or 30-bit for RGB are common).